# validating email in registration is not raising validationError in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-registration

In my `registration`, I am enforcing that `email-id` is unique. That is if a user exists with that email-id, I want to `raise` a `forms.ValidationError`.

Here is my `form.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #define fields
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password1','password2')

    def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                print user.email
                print user.username
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email address already exists. Did you forget your password?")
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

my `view.py`:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for signing up")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/register_success")

    args={}
    args['form']=MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,"register.html",args)
```

when I `register` a `user` with same email id, it does not throw `validationError`. but simply return the `register.html` but no duplicate user is added.

why is it not throwing `validationError`?

I added a couple of `print` statements in `forms.py (above)` to `print` the `username` and `email` that I get from `User.object.get(email=email)` and it correctly prints the `name` and `email id` of previously `registered user`. so the control proceeds till there but it is not throwing `validationError`

`EDIT:`

I also tried creating a  `brand new user`, but having `passoword` fields `Not match`.
 still, I do not get any `error` message. but it simply redirects to `register.html`

EDIT:

`template/register.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}


<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="register"/>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

In this template, `error` gets displayed automatically right above the `field` where the `error occurs`. I don't have to do {{ form.email.error }}. However, I do not have a way to customize the `error`. eg `bold` or some css to them. Is that possible?

Comment: This smells like an html template that does not display the error in your form. Try adding ``{{ form.errors }}`` in your template and see what happens.

Comment: I added that to template still that did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django forms catch `ValidationError` exception and adds error to form `_errors` dict. This code from django `BaseForm._clean_fields` method:

```
        try:
            # ...
            if hasattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name):
                value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
                self.cleaned_data[name] = value
        except ValidationError as e:
            self._errors[name] = self.error_class(e.messages)
            if name in self.cleaned_data:
                del self.cleaned_data[name]
```

So, by raising `ValidationError` exception you are telling django to add errors to cleaning field and make your form not valid.

You can access field error in template:

```
{{ form.field_name.errors }}
```

and iterate one field errors (django docs [Customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)):

```
{% if form.subject.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```

and all fields errors (django docs [Looping over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)):

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

and display non field errors:

```
 {{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

**update:** you should add `else` block in view. Without `else` you are always create new form:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for signing up")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/register_success")
    else:
        form = MyRegistrationForm()

    args={}
    args['form'] = form
    return render(request,"register.html",args)
```

Comment: what is the fix that is needed? I am not clear with your answer

Comment: I tried `{{  form.email.errors }}` that did not give anything. Does the `ValidationError` redirect to the `register` page

Comment: Amazing! this helped. by default, User model allows unique UserName. i.e if I try to register a new User, with same UserName, it will not register, but I guess we have to explicitly check in template, to throw form.errors. but is `{{ form.field_name.errors }}` is a list or errors or just a string version?

Comment: @eagertoLearn {{ form.field_name.errors }} is iterable, i've added example

Comment: That helped a lot. If I have form errors in all fields, how can I iterate through all the errors. since `field.email.error` or `field.username.error` is specific to `email and username fields`

Comment: @eagertoLearn you can iterate form fields and get errors from each field, i've added example

Comment: Thank you very much!! you are great. I have added my template to edit. can you comment on that.

Comment: @eagertoLearn if you want to customize email field with css you should add fields to form manually (without {{ form.as_p }}) in template. And you should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ :)

Comment: can you please look at this post and give your expert opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492647/how-to-increase-the-range-of-years-to-show-up-in-django-templates