# how to increase the range of years to show up in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In the `signUp` form I am creating, I am pre-populating the `date-of-birth field` to "yesterday".
But the `scroll down menu` for year is limited to 9 years. how can I increase the number of years to show up. It must not be limited. I have attached the image. you can see that there is an `option to choose` only among those nine years. Any ideas how to fix this?

`signups/forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from signups.models import SignUp
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

def yesterday():
    yesterday = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1))
    return yesterday

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(), initial=yesterday)
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp
```

`signups/models.py:`

```
from django.db import models 
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from blogapp.models import Post


class SignUp(models.Model):
    #null in database
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    #default is null=false, blank=false, email is necessary
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    #when created make timestamp but not when updated
    timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField()
    date_of_birth=models.DateTimeField()
    myPosts=models.ManyToManyField(Post)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.email,encoding='utf-8',strings_only=False,errors='strict')
```

`signup/views.py:`

```
def signup_view(request):
    form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it=form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for signing up")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/register_success")
    else:
        args={}
        args['form']=form
        return render(request,"signup.html",args)
```

`templates/signup.html:`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Join Now</h2>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="register"/>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: _It must not be limited_. It has to, that widget is rendered in the `html` as `options` inside a `select` tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a years argument into SelectDateWidget as follows:

```
SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2100))
```

Although this will not accept an infinite range, under most circumstances it should do.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget), you can also add month restraints in the development version :)

If you wanted to dynamically change the range with time, you could do something similar to this:

```
from datetime import datetime
## range would be the difference between the current year, 
## and the farthest year into the future or past you would want to include.
date_range = 100    
this_year = datetime.now().year
     ### django code here ###

 SelectDateWidget(years=range(this_year - date_range, this_year + date_range))
```

Comment: Good answer, you can add the link to the widget's doc for completeness :)

Comment: this will need maintainence I guess. say after l0 years, you want to increase the range. you have to pull up this code and change. is that ideal?

Comment: @eagertoLearn you can change the `range` to `range(datetime.now().year - 80, datetime.now().year)`

Comment: lennart: that helped thanks. just to let you know since `range` is keyword in python, it is not allowed for assignments. I am sure you know it.

Comment: @eagertoLearn glad you noticed that, and kudos to Paulo Bu as well

Comment: pretty weirdly, adding years attribute to a Custom class inheriting SelectDateWidget does not affect the years attribute values of the widget

Comment: ok, now I understand. instead of passing it as an attribute of the child class, I pass it to the form field widget instance. e.g. 
deadline = forms.DateField(
        label = _('deadline'),
        widget = forms.DateInput(
            years = [year for year in range(timezone.now().year, timezone.now().year + 50)],
        ),
        required = False,
        initial=timezone.now().date